# Reverse engineering a zImage

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

So I have a custom kernel for an embedded arm device which I had worked on some time ago. I've revisited the project but since have reinstalled Ubuntu on my development machine. I can't compile a new zImage correctly as before. I have found an old SD which card which has the correctly compiled and working zImage.

I suspect I'm missing some build option configuration which the old zImage had. Is there a way to reverse engineer and figure out exactly how my older zImage was created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Only works if you have CONFIG_IKCONFIG enabled in the zImage.

You can extract old config using ./scripts/extract-ikconfig from the linux kernel or ./scripts/ikconfig (depending on the version of the source) if your kernel was compiled with CONFIG_IKCONFIG enabled (usually is by default)

## Without CONFIG_IKCONFIG

Hope that you also have a config.gz along with your zImage on the SD card :P

Comment: I did not have CONFIG_IKCONFIG set, but I after messing with build options I managed to get it working anyways. I'll be sure to have this set to enabled next time around just in case! Thanks :)